# display many rows using a foreach in an array

Tags: php, foreach

Im'y trying to do something like that but it does not work.

$resDisplayFormation is a query which returns many rows, and i need to display all the rows in my table, this file is a file called by an ajax function that's why i have to do my foreach a like that

**UPDATE :**

```
<?php 

include('opendb2.php');
if(isset($_POST['idSalarie'])){ 
$displayFormation = $bdd->prepare('SELECT * FROM FORMATION WHERE form_id_user = :idSalarie ');
$displayFormation->bindParam(':idSalarie', $_POST['idSalarie']);
$displayFormation->execute();
$resDisplayFormation=$displayFormation->fetch(PDO::FETCH_ASSOC);

$displayForm = $bdd->prepare(
    'SELECT poste_nom, ups_type_contrat, serv_nom, serv_id_resp, user_credit_cpf, user_indice_salarial, form_intitule, form_organisme, form_date, form_duree,
     FLOOR( DATEDIFF( CURDATE( ) , user_dateentree ) /365 ) AS dateEntree 
     FROM USER 
     INNER JOIN USER_POSTE_SERVICE 
        ON USER.user_id= USER_POSTE_SERVICE.ups_poste_id  
     INNER JOIN POSTE 
        ON USER_POSTE_SERVICE. ups_poste_id = POSTE.poste_id 
     INNER JOIN SERVICE 
        ON USER_POSTE_SERVICE.ups_id_serv = SERVICE.serv_id
     INNER JOIN FORMATION
        ON FORMATION.form_id_user =  USER.user_id
     WHERE user_id = :idSalarie
        ORDER BY user_nom ASC');
$displayForm->bindParam(':idSalarie', $_POST['idSalarie']);
$displayForm->execute();
$resDisplayForm=$displayForm->fetch(PDO::FETCH_ASSOC);
$data = array( 'resDisplayForm'=>'');
foreach ($resDisplayForm as $key => $value) {
    $data['resDisplayForm'][$key] .=  $value;
}
$data['salarie'] = '          
    <div class="form-group">
        <label for="poste_nom" class="col-sm-2 control-label">Poste occupé</label>
        <div class="col-sm-10">
            <input type="text" class="form-control" name="poste_nom" readonly>
        </div>
    </div> 
    <div class="form-group">
        <label for="ups_type_contrat" class="col-sm-2 control-label">Type de contrat</label>
        <div class="col-sm-10">
            <input type="text" class="form-control" name="ups_type_contrat" readonly>
        </div>
    </div> 
    <div class="form-group">
        <label for="serv_nom" class="col-sm-2 control-label" readonly>Service</label>
        <div class="col-sm-10">
            <input type="text" class="form-control" name="serv_nom" readonly>
        </div>
    </div> 
    <div class="form-group">
        <label for="serv_id_resp" class="col-sm-2 control-label" readonly>Responsable</label>
        <div class="col-sm-10">
            <input type="text" class="form-control" name="serv_id_resp" readonly>
        </div>
    </div>
    <div class="form-group">
        <label for="user_credit_cpf" class="col-sm-2 control-label" readonly>Crédits CPF</label>
        <div class="col-sm-2">
            <input type="text" class="form-control" name="user_credit_cpf" readonly>
        </div>
        <label for="user_indice_salarial" class="col-sm-2 control-label" readonly>Indice Salarial</label>
        <div class="col-sm-1">
            <input type="text" class="form-control" name="user_indice_salarial" readonly>
        </div>
        <label for="dateEntree" class="col-sm-2 control-label">Ancienneté</label>
        <div class="col-sm-2 input-group">
            <input type="text" class="form-control" name="dateEntree" aria-describedby="basic-addon2" readonly>
            <span class="input-group-addon" id="basic-addon2">années</span>
        </div>
    </div>';

$data['formation'] .= '
    <div class="table-responsive">
        <table class="table table-bordered" style="width: auto !important;">
         <thead style="font-weight: bold;">’’
           <tr>
              <td>N</td>
              <td>Intitulé</td>
              <td>Organisme</td>
              <td>Date</td>
              <td>Durée (en heures)</td>
              <td>Eval. à chaud / à froid</td>
              <td>Dispositif utilisé</td>
            </tr>
          </thead>
          <tbody class="table-striped">';

            foreach ($resDisplayFormation as $ligne) {
            $data['formation'] .= '
            <tr>
                <td>

                </td>
                <td>
                    <input type="text" class="form-control" name="form_intitule" id="form_intitule" readonly>
                </td>
                <td>
                    <input type="text" class="form-control" name="form_organisme" id="form_organisme" readonly>
                </td>
                <td>
                    <input type="text" class="form-control" name="form_date" id="form_date" readonly>
                </td>
                <td>
                    <input type="text" class="form-control" name="form_duree" id="form_duree" readonly>
                </td>
                <td></td>
                <td></td>
            </tr>';
            }
            $data['formation'] .= '

          </tbody>
        </table>
    </div>';
}

echo json_encode($data);die;
?>
```

**My AJAX :**

```
jQuery(document).ready(function($) {
$('#idSalarie').change(function(){
    //on recupere la valeur de l'attribut value pour afficher tel ou tel resultat
    var req=$('#idSalarie').val();
    //requête ajax, appel du fichier function.php
    $.ajax({
        type: "POST",
        url: "lib/function.php",
        data: "idSalarie="+req,
        dataType : "json",
        //affichage de l'erreur en cas de problème
        error: function(XMLHttpRequest, textStatus, errorThrown) {
            alert(XMLHttpRequest + '--' + textStatus + '--' + errorThrown);
        },
        //function s'il n'y a pas de probleme
        success:function(data){
            //On affiche la réponse du serveur
            $('.salarie').empty();
            $('.salarie').prepend(data.salarie);
            $('input[name=poste_nom]').val(data.resDisplayForm.poste_nom).val();
            $('input[name=ups_type_contrat]').val(data.resDisplayForm.ups_type_contrat).val();
            $('input[name=serv_nom]').val(data.resDisplayForm.serv_nom).val();
            $('input[name=serv_id_resp]').val(data.resDisplayForm.serv_id_resp).val();
            $('input[name=user_credit_cpf]').val(data.resDisplayForm.user_credit_cpf).val();
            $('input[name=dateEntree]').val(data.resDisplayForm.dateEntree).val();
            $('input[name=user_indice_salarial]').val(data.resDisplayForm.user_indice_salarial).val();

            $('.formation').empty();
            $('.formation').prepend(data.formation)
            $('input[name=form_id]').val(data.resDisplayForm.form_id).val();
            $('input[name=form_intitule]').val(data.resDisplayForm.form_intitule).val();
            $('input[name=form_organisme]').val(data.resDisplayForm.form_organisme).val();
            $('input[name=form_date]').val(data.resDisplayForm.form_date).val();
            $('input[name=form_duree]').val(data.resDisplayForm.form_duree).val();


        }
    });
});
});
```

Comment: At a quick glance, you probably want `$data['formation'] .= '` instead of `$data['formation'] = '` both within and after your `foreach` loop.

Comment: i have edited my code but it displays 6 times the same row ..

Comment: How do you expect to get different rows when you don't use a variable within your `foreach`?  What do you think would make the rows different?

Answer (score 0):

Inside foreach instead of

```
$data['formation'] = '
```

you had to write

```
$data['formation'] .= '
```

and after foreach you also had to write

```
$data['formation'] .= '
```

This will concatenate all of you rows in correct HTML table

UPDATE

In this part of code you didn't get any value from $ligne param and dont write it in table cells. Thats why you will get 6 identical rows

```
foreach ($resDisplayFormation as $ligne) {
            $data['formation'] .= '
            <tr>
                <td>

                </td>
                <td>
                    <input type="text" class="form-control" name="form_intitule" id="form_intitule" readonly>
                </td>
                <td>
                    <input type="text" class="form-control" name="form_organisme" id="form_organisme" readonly>
                </td>
                <td>
                    <input type="text" class="form-control" name="form_date" id="form_date" readonly>
                </td>
                <td>
                    <input type="text" class="form-control" name="form_duree" id="form_duree" readonly>
                </td>
                <td></td>
                <td></td>
            </tr>';
            }
```

It should be smth like this

```
foreach ($resDisplayFormation as $ligne) {
            $data['formation'] .= '
            <tr>
                <td>

                </td>
                <td>
                    <input type="text" class="form-control" name="form_intitule" id="form_intitule" value='.$ligne["form_intitule"].' readonly>
                </td>
                <td>
                    <input type="text" class="form-control" name="form_organisme" id="form_organisme" value='.$ligne["form_organisme"].' readonly>
                </td>
                <td>
                    <input type="text" class="form-control" name="form_date" id="form_date" value='.$ligne["form_date"].' readonly>
                </td>
                <td>
                    <input type="text" class="form-control" name="form_duree" id="form_duree" value='.$ligne["form_duree"].' readonly>
                </td>
                <td></td>
                <td></td>
            </tr>';
            }
```

Comment: yes i know, but i need to repeat all of my <tr> not only the inputs, that's me problem ^^

Comment: a small hint besides the main problem: the way the code is written at the moment, you get the same id several times (once per <tr>), which violates the standard and can lead to unexpected behaviour when selecting elements per javascript

Comment: what you want a screen or my html ?

Comment: i want to see your html in "$data['formation']" variable before executing "echo json_encode($data);die;"

Comment: i have edited my post, you can see the ajax function, and the html is juste two div (formation and salarie)

Comment: your values data.resDisplayForm.* in ajax response will be always UNDEFINED

your json response contains only 2 items data.resDisplayForm and data.formation both of this items are HTML (not json)

Comment: and that's why i have 6 rows in my table ?

Comment: strings like "$('input[name=*]').val .........." in your callback do not needed ) 

just look in code listed after my text "It should be smth like this" 
if you change your code inside foreach according my note you will get correct table

Comment: Let us [continue this discussion in chat](http://chat.stackoverflow.com/rooms/100683/discussion-between-lucas-frugier-and-klin).

Answer (score 0):

```
    $data['formation'] .= '
    <div class="table-responsive">
        <table class="table table-bordered" style="width: auto !important;">
         <thead style="font-weight: bold;">’’
           <tr>
              <td>N</td>
              <td>Intitulé</td>
              <td>Organisme</td>
              <td>Date</td>
              <td>Durée (en heures)</td>
              <td>Eval. à chaud / à froid</td>
              <td>Dispositif utilisé</td>
            </tr>
          </thead>
          <tbody class="table-striped">';

            foreach ($resDisplayFormation as $ligne) {
            $data['formation'] .= '
            <tr>
                <td>

                </td>
                <td>
                    <input type="text" class="form-control" name="form_intitule" id="form_intitule" value="'.$ligne['form_intitule'].'" readonly>
                </td>
                <td>
                    <input type="text" class="form-control" name="form_organisme" id="form_organisme" value="'.$ligne['form_organisme'].'" readonly>
                </td>
                <td>
                    <input type="text" class="form-control" name="form_date" id="form_date" value="'.$ligne['form_date'].'" readonly>
                </td>
                <td>
                    <input type="text" class="form-control" name="form_duree" id="form_duree" value="'.$ligne['form_duree'].'" readonly>
                </td>
                <td></td>
                <td></td>
            </tr>';
            }
            $data['formation'] .= '

          </tbody>
        </table>
    </div>';
}

echo json_encode($data); die;
```

Comment: <input type="text" class="form-control" name="form_date" id="form_date" readonly value="'.$ligne['ITEM NAME'].'">

Comment: for each row i need to repeat the <tr>